# Object Required error '424' - automated daily refresh

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to the VBA and I try to create an automated daily refresh of 2 different worksheets of my workbook. Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Thank you in advance!

```
Sub autoRefreshClean()

Dim myRangeClean As range
Dim myRangeVprod As range
Dim wsclean As Worksheet
Dim wsvprod As Worksheet
Set wsvprod = ThisWorkbook(4)
Set wsclean = ThisWorkbook(5)
Set myRangeClean = wsclean.range("C2:G1059")
Set myRangeVprod = wsvprod.range("C2:G1059")

Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:22:10 pm"), "RefreshAll"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:22:10 pm"), "Recalculate"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:22:10 pm"), "DataFileExport"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:24:10 pm"), "RefreshAll"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:10 pm"), "Recalculate"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:26:10 pm"), "DataFileExport"
End Sub

Sub RefreshAll()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub

Sub Recalculate()

Application.Calculate

End Sub

Sub DataFileExport()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myRangeClean.Copy
myRangeVprod.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\foo", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myRangeClean.Copy
myRangeVprod.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\foo", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

My two different Sheets are named Clean and Vprod and they have the same cell range where the report builder is being loaded. I want the report builder to run daily and refresh each sheet.

Comment: On what line do you get your error. Also include the error(message) in your post as well.

Comment: Also you never set your displayalerts back on, might be wise to do so.

Comment: What is `Set wsvprod = ThisWorkbook(4)` supposed to do? `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook in which the code resides.